# How to use time as a trigger for a state in a simple study planner program

Tags: python, if-statement, time, conditional-statements

This is my first project in Python and I am trying to make a study reminder that will tell me to swap between passive and active learning and I hope to further on make it respond to input though an interface, but for now I want to use time.localtime(time.time()) to get hold of the timestamp, the integer that is the even/uneven hour of the now. I could just look at the clock but this is meant to give me some kind of output like two different colours but mot important be my training platform. So how can I get hold of integers thru time.
I´ve been trying some different ideas.

Well this code is fragmented but anyway this is where I´m at right now. This is some combo of a function and a list that is not ready at all, it´s only fragments of different tests.

These are techniques I´ve looked into but I have not been able to make any of it pull anything from any time module that I´ve tried. Maybe It has just not been visible/ printed.

Booleans

---

if/else

---

```
if num % 2 == 0:
    pass # Even 
else:
    pass # Odd
```

---

Python Conditions and If statements
Python supports the usual logical conditions from mathematics:
* Equals: a == b
* Not Equals: a != b
* Less than: a < b
* Less than or equal to: a <= b
* Greater than: a > b

### * Greater than or equal to: a >= b

```
import datetime

print ("Current date and time: " , datetime.datetime.now())

    def time_even_or_uneven():
        if datetime.datetime.now % 2 == 0:
            print("Number is even")
        else:
            print("Number is odd")

#This is where my questions start
# Uncomplete test code
# I´m trying to find a way to start off a function and later on several # functions from the timestamp I get from the code above. 

            print(datetime.datetime.now % 2 = 0)


import datetime...
    File "", line 12
        print(datetime.datetime.now % 2 = 0)
         ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

## Without the faulty line I get the time stamp from the time module:

Current date and time:  2019-07-04 13:58:15.811722

I don´t see anything from the function "time_even_or_uneven"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
    datetime.datetime.now().time().hour%2==0
    or
    datetime.datetime.now().time().minute%2==0
    or
    datetime.datetime.now().time().second%2==0
```

Comment: Thanx alot fixalot! I got a True response and a False response and I can now play around with that!

Answer (score 0):

As "datetime.datetime.now" returns object value with its memory address.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with your code. The error you are receiving  is because you use a single `=` instead of a double `==`. Single is for assignment, and you can't do that as an expression.

But after fixing that you'll imediately hit another error because `datetime.datetime.now` is a function. thus `%` is not defined. Rather call ``datetime.datetime.now()` to get the value returned by the function instead of the function object.

However that still won't work as `datetime.datetime.now()` is a `datetime.datetime` object, basically a tuple of integers which also doesn't define `%`. So instead rather get the days or seconds or something that is an integer i.e. `datetime.datetime.now().second % 2 == 0` is valid to check for an even second.

But before any of this, you need to ask yourself what does an even date mean? There is no standard definition for this so you'll need to define it more explicitly so that readers of your code understand what you mean by it.

For clarity, here are all those steps with each of the error messages:

#### Using `=` instead of `==`:

```
print(datetime.datetime.now % 2 = 0)
```

> ```
>   File "<ipython-input-17-9fea3c9eff3e>", line 1
>     print(datetime.datetime.now % 2 = 0)
>          ^ SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
> ```

#### Trying to apply `%` to the function object rather than the function's returned value (i.e. leaving of the `()`):

```
print(datetime.datetime.now % 2 == 0)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/dgolding/PycharmProjects/dsdk-pg/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> ```
>
> line 2963, in run_code
>           exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           print(datetime.datetime.now % 2 == 0)
>       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

#### Trying to apply `%` to a datetime object

```
print(datetime.datetime.now() % 2 == 0)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/dgolding/PycharmProjects/dsdk-pg/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> ```
>
> line 2963, in run_code
>           exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           print(datetime.datetime.now() % 2 == 0)
>       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

#### Finally, something valid, applying `%` to an integer:

```
print(datetime.datetime.now().second % 2 == 0)
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
#This is how the code looks now thanks to a combination of helpful comments:
#Thanks Rahul. Thanks Dan. Thanks Rishu.

import datetime

print ("Current date and time: " , datetime.datetime.now())

# Gives me a True/False output
datetime.datetime.now().hour%2==0

if datetime.datetime.now().hour%2 == 0:
        print("You could consider some active training the next hour")
else:
        print("You could consider some passive studies the next hour")
```